# Preloading Images: Problem in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, image, preloader

The following Code Works in every browser accept every version of IE, can someone please help! There seems to be a problem with the cat.onload method....I have done so many tests and am at a loss...any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

```
var bannerCount = 0;
var bannerImgsArr = new Array();
bannerImgsArr[0] ='image1.jpg';
bannerImgsArr[1] ='image2.jpg';
bannerImgsArr[2] ='image3.jpg';
bannerImgsArr[3] ='image4.jpg';

$(document).ready(function() {
  preloadBannerImages();
});

function preloadBannerImages(){
    //create new image object
    var cat = new Image();

    //give Image src attribute the image file name
    cat.src =bannerImgsArr[bannerCount];

    //if the counter represents the last image in the current gallery enter here: 
    if(bannerCount == 3){

        //When the image has been loaded the following function is exicuted 
        cat.onload = function() {
            //Removes the LOADING message hard coded into the html page;
            document.getElementById("bigbox").removeChild(document.getElementById("loading"));
        }

    }else{

        //when current image is finished loading increments the img index and 
        //calls the loading function again for the next image in the gallery

        bannerCount++;
        cat.onload =preloadBannerImages;

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the `onload` handler for the image after setting the `src` property. Do the one before the other.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you really need to elaborate what  exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### [edit]

The function most likely ends and calls itself again before the image is downloaded, so the image isn't cached. Load the images into a persistent store (e.g. array) that hangs around until they are all downlaoded and cached.

#### [/edit]

You don't have to wait for the DOM to be ready to load images:

```
var bannerCount = 0;
var bannerImgsArr = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg'];
var imageArray = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=bannerImgsArr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  imageArray[i]  = new Image();
  imageArray[i].src = bannerImgsArr[i];
}
```

Now when the DOM is ready, you can use one of the preloaded images.

```
...
cat.src = imageArr[bannerCount].src;
...
```

Comment: Did you miss the `var cat = new Image();`

Comment: It's irrelevant, the images are never stored. Having the function call itself using onload is equivalent to a loop. A reference to the created *image* object is never kept so IE (probably) doesn't bother to finish downloading it. So a reference to each *image* object must be kept at least until the image finished downloading. And there is no need for recursive calling, the images can be downloaded in parallel. There is no need wait for the load event of one before attempting to load the next, the browser will handle that.

Comment: no need to store them.. once they have loaded they are cached by the browser and can be used instantly. The whole idea of the OP is to wait for images to load (*images that start loading after the dom is ready*) so he can remove the loading progress image. He **wants** to load the images after the DOM is loaded, and wants to know when **all** dynamic images have completed loading.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the onload-event of images, it may not fire if the image was loaded before and comes from the cache